# String to textview in Android not displaying like it did before within custom adapter

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am using the same custom adapter format that I used in one of my other apps. I only changed the string references but I am getting the following error when running the app:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

I've been trying to wrap my brain around this but I can't figure out what the problem is. Everything is exactly the same as in the other app but for some reason doesn't work in this one. Everything is exactly the same. The only difference is the database table that the data is being drawn from. Here's my getView that is producing the error:

```
public class Holder
{
    TextView title;
    TextView description;
    NetworkImageView img;
    RatingBar rating;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);
    holder.title=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
    holder.img=(NetworkImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.productPic);
    holder.rating=(RatingBar)rowView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2);
    holder.title.setText(result.get(position).getName());
    holder.rating.setRating(Float.valueOf(result.get(position).getRating().toString()));

    // If you are using NetworkImageView
    holder.img.setImageUrl(result.get(position).getImageURL(), VolleyController.getInstance().getImageLoader());

    return rowView;
}
```

My row data/model is exactly the same too. The line that is giving the error is:

```
holder.title.setText(result.get(position).getName());
```

In my RowData model getName is like this:

```
public String getName(){
    return name;
```

Comment: does `R.id.productName` exist in `R.layout.product_row`

Comment: Yeah double check that productName is available in product_row

Comment: @Steve C. please find below solution..and let me know in case of concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace yours code with these lines of code . In yours code you are not using the `View convertView` of `getView()` method of `BaseAdapter` instead of it, you used your own `View` that is **rowView** ,therefore you are facing these problem.So use the View of the `getView()` method of `adapter` class

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Holder holder=new Holder();

    if (convertView == null) {

     convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_row, null);
     holder.title=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productName);
     holder.img=(NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productPic);
     holder.rating=(RatingBar)convertView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar2);

     convertView.setTag(holder);
   }
   else
   {
       holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
   }
       holder.title.setText(result.get(position).getName());
       holder.rating.setRating(Float.valueOf(result.get(position).getRating().toString()));


    // If you are using NetworkImageView
     holder.img.setImageUrl(result.get(position).getImageURL(), VolleyController.getInstance().getImageLoader());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I did have to change ViewHolder to Holder because it gave a mismatch exception error that it was expecting Adapter.Holder but instead found RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Also found that I was referencing the wrong TextView id. Everything works smoothly now. Thank you

Comment: @SteveC. Happy to help bro :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all I ask you the question why you used `View Holder`. because It is the wrong/wrost implementation of `view Holder`. please read this blog it will help you to understand the `view holder` pattern
https://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

And please check the id of `TextView` in **product_row.xml.** I thought its just a misspelled id of `TestView`.

Comment: I used "Holder" because it was part of a Volley PHP MySql tutorial I followed.

Comment: ok but you can Ignore this. volley is not related to Holder anyhow. and can i see the product_row.xml

Comment: and I think your accepted answer is even not related to your problem, your problem is  wrong id of textView. that was mention in my answer. Thanks

Comment: I thought it might be the issue of the id but when I changed that to the correct id, I had a plethora of other issues with the "Holder". I am checking out your link now as I didn't now about ViewHolder. Very educational. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Bro.. Happy to help!

Comment: I was looking over your link and it seems like the very logical thing to do. I appreciate it. I have a question though, it doesn't specify the import declaration for ViewHolder and would it work with a basic listview in the xml?

Comment: Thanks @Steve actually Before RecyclerView  ViewHolder is just a pattern It means ViewHolder is a custom class developed by developer you have to create your own class you can name it whatever you want. the basic purpose of viewholder pattern is to reuse the  calling of  convertView.findViewbyId() . this method uses recursion that means complex design takes more time to execute. without using this pattern you are finding the view that was already find.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `View` reference from the `getView()` do not create separate `View` .

Use

```
 `holder.title=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.productName);`
```

it may solve the problem